# Calculating limits. Am I correct? (with working)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]
This is my working for the first two questions (i and ii). Does anyone know how to work out iii? Also, is my working correct? Any feedback is appreciated. I also did a rough calculation of iii and I think the answer is supposed to be 5 but I'm not too sure of the working.

(i)
We are finding the limit as x approaches -2. According to the system of equations, we should look at where it says -2 ≤ x ≤ 3 because x is approaching -2 and -2 fits into this system.
So Ix^2 - 4I if -2 ≤ x ≤ 3 is what we're looking at. What we're finding is the limit if x approaches -2. So let's replace x with -2.
Ix^2 - 4I
I(-2)^2 - 4I
I(4) - 4I
I0I
0
lim f(x) as x app. -2 = 0.

(ii)
lim f(x) as x app. 2. This fits into Ix^2 - 4I if -2 ≤ x ≤ 3. Same reasoning as above. After it says if, it says if -2 ≤ x ≤ 3 and if we replace 2 for x here it makes sense. So now we replace 2 for x where it says Ix^2 - 4I.
Ix^2 - 4I
I(2)^2 - 4I
I(4) - 4I
I0I
0
lim f(x) as x app. 2 = 0.

Answer (score 3):

i) Notice that the function has two different expressions at $2^-$ and $2^+$ and we have
$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{1}{x+2}=-\infty$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2^+}|x^2-4|=0$$
ii) is correct

iii)the same method as i)  and we find
$$\lim_{x\to 3^-}f(x)=5= \lim_{x\to 3^+}f(x)\neq f(0)$$
hence we conclude that $f$ isn't continuous at $3$.

Comment: Your first one-sided limit should be $-\infty$, not $+\infty$.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks

Comment: I see! Are these the correct workings?

Comment: @LauraAnderson Yes your answer should be like this.

Comment: Thank you @Sami! Much appreciated.

Comment: @LauraAnderson You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your solution to (i) you're overlooking that there are points arbitrarily close to $-2$ that fall in the *first* case. Going back to the definition of limit, no matter how small you choose $\delta$, there will always be *some* numbers between $-2-\delta$ and $-2+\delta$ that satisfy $x<-2$, so you have to consider that case too.

For example, what is $f(-2.000001)$? Does that look like it's about to approach $0$?

For (iii), you need the same kind of reasoning, except there are now *three* different cases that are always relevant.

Answer (score 1):

i) Here we need to find the left hand limit of the function f(x)
So, we will go for lim x->-2 1/x+2 = infinity

ii) We have to look for Right hand limit of the function f(x)
So lim x->2 |x^2 - 4| 
 [-2, 3) the function is positive everywhere in it's domain. So we can remove the modulus sign and solve the limit
lim x->2 x^2-4= 0

iii)   Again, we have to find the Right hand limit of f(x) here
So, lim x->3 sqrt(x^2+16) = sqrt(25) = 5

Your rough calculation was right for iii)

Sorry, I'm new here. So I don't know how to add images or any symbols. Hope this helps.